# "Wave Algorithm" (based in Lee's Algorithm) in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a program calculation the shortest way from point A to point B.
I have a map (matrix) with values:

- 0 is block (wall, no way to pass);
- 1 is free way (you can pass);
- 11 is point A (start point);
- 22 is point B (finish point).

I've read a few articles how it should work and tried to realize my own version but got stacked.

In the code below I declare 2 arrays: an array with Map and changed array "visited" while running program demonstrating visited points.

I check the cells in 4 directions (not diagonals) for 1 or 0. If it's 1 (possible to pass), I increase the counter for 1. For do not count the previous cell I'm trying to avoid it by the condition.

As a result I wanna see "visited" matrix with a few lines which shows the way to reach to the point B (1, 2, 3, ... 15).

Right now my map doesn't look like correct, not even close.

What have I missed in my algorithm, what should I take into account and how to fix my program?

Thank you.

P.S. I wrote a few functions implementing a new array with 0 values, counting free to go cells and printing arrays.

main.c:

```
    #include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDTH 8
#define HEIGHT 8

int mapZero(int map[WIDTH][WIDTH]);
int mapPrint(int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT]);
int mapInit(int map[WIDTH][WIDTH]);
int findFreeToGoCells(int map[WIDTH][WIDTH]);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    short int prevPosition;
    short int currPosition;
    short int nextPosition;
    short int lastPosition;

    int visited[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

    unsigned int count;
    unsigned int max;

    mapZero(visited);

    int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT] =
    {
        { 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 22 },

    };

    printf("Matrix of zeroed-visited cells:\n\n");
    mapPrint(visited);

    printf("Matrix of the map:\n\n");
    mapPrint(map);

    printf("Ways: %d\n", findFreeToGoCells(map));

    prevPosition = map[0][0];
    currPosition = 0;

    count = 0;
    max = WIDTH * HEIGHT;

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j)
        {
            if (((i >= 0) && (i < WIDTH)) && ((j >= 0) && (j < HEIGHT)))
            {
                // [i + 1][j] 
                if (map[i + 1][j] == 1)
                {
                    map[i][j] = prevPosition;
                    if (prevPosition)
                        visited[i + 1][j] = count++;

                }
                if (map[i + 1][j] == 0)
                {
                    visited[i + 1][j] = map[i + 1][j];
                }

                // [i - 1][j]
                if (map[i - 1][j] == 1)
                {
                    map[i][j] = prevPosition;
                    if (prevPosition)
                        visited[i - 1][j] = count++;
                }
                if (map[i - 1][j] == 0)
                {
                    visited[i - 1][j] = map[i - 1][j];
                }

                // [i][j + 1]
                if (map[i][j + 1] == 1)
                {
                    map[i][j] = prevPosition;
                    if (prevPosition)
                        visited[i][j + 1] = count++;
                }
                if (map[i][j + 1] == 0)
                {
                    visited[i][j + 1] = map[i][j + 1];
                }

                // [i][j - 1]
                if (map[i][j - 1] == 1)
                {
                    map[i][j] = prevPosition;
                    visited[i][j - 1] = map[i][j - 1];
                    if (prevPosition)
                        visited[i][j - 1] = count++;
                }
                if (map[i][j - 1] == 0)
                {
                    visited[i][j - 1] = map[i][j - 1];
                }

            } // map borders check (finished)
              //count++;
        }
    }

    printf("count: %d\n", count);

    if (count > 1000)
    {
        printf("The way couldn't be found\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Matrix of visited cells:\n\n");
        mapPrint(visited);
        //printf("Short way: %d\n", findShortWay(map[7][7]));
    }
    printf("Ways: %d\n", findFreeToGoCells(visited));

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int mapZero(int map[WIDTH][WIDTH])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j)
        {
            map[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int mapPrint(int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j)
        {
            printf("%2d  ", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int findFreeToGoCells(int map[WIDTH][WIDTH])
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j)
        {
            if (map[i][j] == 1 || map[i][j] == 99) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here the shortest way is always 15 cells

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the nested loops in the `main` function, the expression `((i >= 0) && (i < WIDTH)) && ((j >= 0) && (j < HEIGHT))` will *always* be true.

That means you *will* go out of bounds of your arrays.

I suggest you check value of `i` as part of doing e.g. `if (map[i + 1][j] == 1)`. Perhaps something like

```
if (i < WIDTH - 1 && map[i + 1][j] == 1) { ... }
```

If you do it similar for the other places as well (for when you do `i - 1` check `i > 0`) then you should not go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

Another possibility that's similar to the above check is to have one check for `i` (or `j`) being in range and then do the check you have now. Sonething like

```
if (i < WIDTH - 1)
{
    if (map[i + 1][j] == 1) { ... }

    if (map[i + 1][j] == 0) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to ask about bounds.
Anyway, the other things look right, isn't it? I mean the logic and the algorithm. I don't know if it's enough and if I should keep current coordinates (x,y).

Comment: Maybe removing the test altogether and changing the range of the for loops would do the trick.