# Wave Algorithm (Lee's Algorithm): incorrect final matrix

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a program calculating the shortest way from point A to point B.
I have a map (matrix) with values:

- 0 is block (wall, no way to pass);
- 1 is free way (you can pass);
- 2 is start point;

In the code below I declare 2 arrays: an array " map"and changed array "visited" while running program demonstrating visited points.

I check the cells in 4 directions (not diagonals) for 1 or 0. If it's 1 (possible to pass), I increase the counter for 1. For do not count the previous cell I'm trying to avoid it by the condition. I realized that in two one-dimensional arrays {1 0 -1 0} and { 0, 1, 0, -1 } to check neighbor points (what mean i check [i+1][j], [i-1][j], [i][j+1] and [i][j-1]).

As a result I wanna see "visited" matrix with a few lines which shows the way to reach to the point B (1, 2, 3, ... 15). I wanna find the way to map[7][7] point.

Right now the error here that I do count++ for the previous position. How to avoid that?

Thank you.

P.S. I wrote a few functions implementing a new array with 0 values, counting free to go cells and printing arrays.

main.c:

```
    #include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDTH 8
#define HEIGHT 8

int mapZero(int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT]);
int mapPrint(int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT]);
int mapInit(int map[WIDTH][WIDTH]);
int findFreeToGoCells(int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT]);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    bool stop;
    unsigned int count;
    unsigned int max;

    int visited[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT] =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },

    };

    mapZero(visited);
    printf("Matrix of zeroed-visited cells:\n\n");
    mapPrint(visited);
    printf("Matrix of the map:\n\n");
    mapPrint(map);
    printf("Free to go cells: %d\n\n", findFreeToGoCells(map));

    max = WIDTH * HEIGHT - 1;
    visited[0][0] = map[0][0];
    count = 0;
    visited[0][0] = 0;

    int di[4] = { 1, -1, 0, 0 };
    int dj[4] = { 0, 0, 1, -1 };

    //do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j)
            {
                if (visited[i][j] == count)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
                    {
                        int i_check = i + di[k];
                        int j_check = j + dj[k];

                        if ((i_check >= 0 && i_check < WIDTH) && (j_check >= 0 && j_check < HEIGHT) && (map[i_check][j_check] != 0))
                        {
                            visited[i_check][j_check] = count + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }// while (visited[7][7] == 0);

    if (count > max + 99999) 
        printf("The way couldn't be found\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Matrix of visited cells:\n\n");
        mapPrint(visited);
        printf("Free to go cells from [0][0] to [7][7]: %d\n", findFreeToGoCells(visited));
    }

/*************************************************************************************/
/*************************************************************************************/

    int len;
    int x = 7;
    int y = 7;
    int x_path[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    int y_path[WIDTH * HEIGHT];

    len = visited[7][7];
    count = len;

    while (count > 0)
    {
        x_path[count] = x;
        y_path[count] = y;            
        count--;
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
        {
            int i_check = x + di[k];
            int j_check = y + dj[k];
            if ((i_check >= 0 && i_check < WIDTH) && (j_check >= 0 && j_check < HEIGHT) && (map[i_check][j_check] == count))
            {
                x = x + di[k];
                y = y + dj[k];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    x_path[0] = 0;
    y_path[0] = 0;
    printf("\nThe shortest way consist of %d cells\nThere are %d the shortest way to reach th the final point\n\n", len, findFreeToGoCells(visited)-len);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int mapZero(int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j)
        {
            map[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int mapPrint(int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j)
        {
            printf("%2d  ", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int findFreeToGoCells(int map[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j)
        {
            if (map[i][j] != 0) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Wave Algorithm" (based in Lee's Algorithm) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633690/wave-algorithm-based-in-lees-algorithm-in-c)

Comment: @EugeneSh. This problem is a little different and it didn't solve what I wanted

Comment: Code has dimensions mixed a bit in `int map[WIDTH][WIDTH])`, `visited[iy][ix] = count + 1;` --> should not that be `visited[ix][iy]`?

Comment: @chux yes, it is. I've corrected the code and added one condition before for (k = 0; k < 4; ++k). It checks if the cell was already visited

Comment: @chux it actually change nothing

Comment: With `WIDTH 8
 HEIGHT 8` the same yes, but not if they differ.  As in `int mapZero(int map[WIDTH][WIDTH])` and `int findFreeToGoCells(int map[WIDTH][WIDTH])`

Comment: Try `stop = !true; ... if() stop = !false;`

Comment: @chux It also changes nothing. I think the problem is in the conditions and I still can not understand where

Comment: You should identify this as a continuation of your previous question on the same topic, but specify that the circumstances have changed.  You could also accept the answer to the other question to indicate that it helped you (assuming it did).  That helps indicate that the problem identifies there is as resolved as it can be, and that this is a different problem with a development of the code described in the other question.  When you ask a follow-on question, it's as well to admit that it's a follow-on so as to avoid having to deal with the 'possible duplicate' votes.

Comment: Can you update your result with the code changes you made?

Comment: @chux It doesn't depend on this condition, I can't go trhough the condition  if (visited[i][j] == count) more then 2 times => my matrix will be zeroed

Comment: Now the points [1][1] and [1][2] are wrong what doesn't give to find another one way to reach to the final position [7][7]

Comment: There error here that I do count++ for the previous position. How to avoid that?

Comment: The code keeps evolving - that does not make for a good post/question as we have a moving target -making the question unclear.